# Working on this Java project where I need to be able to delete data from the database on user's request

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

The query inside MySQL is working:

```
DELETE FROM f9.yoo 
WHERE account_tags = '#8GGGJPUR9'
```

I can delete data inside MySQL, but the problem is whenever I try to remove the `account_tags` from my Java application, it throws an error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM f9.yoo
> WHERE account_tags = '#8GGGJPUR9'' at line 2

Here's my Java SQL query:

```
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+databaseName+"."+tableName+";\n" +
        "DELETE FROM "+databaseName+"."+tableName+"\n" +
        "WHERE account_tags = '"+AccountTag+"';";

statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

The error isn't giving me much to work with, so I really have no idea what is wrong with the program.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is the attempt to execute two queries in the same command.  Why do you have the `SELECT` there?

Comment: remove the select part, your query should start from `DELETE` also you should use executeUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `allowMultiQueries=true`

If not then you can add that while you sending the connecting request to your database. So you need to append the `allowMultiQueries=true` in your to database URL.

Like this:

`String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";`

Comment: Thank you, yes it seems the double querry in a single statement was the problem, i've fixed that and it's not working. I copy and pasted the code from my first project and which i use as a template and forgot to remove the select statement. thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM "+databaseName+"."+tableName+"\n" +
        "WHERE account_tags = ?";
try (PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sq)) {
    statement.setString(1, AccountTag);
    int updateCount = statement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.printf("%s: %d records deleted.%n", tableName, updateCount);
}
```

The only thing used is the DELETE, for which one should use `executeUpdate`.

One **definitely** should use a PreparedStatement as many code checkers will give alarms otherwise. It escapes things like `'`, handles types of the arguments, and possible conversions, and especially is a security feature against **SQL injection**.

- The System.out usage is bad style, better would be using a logger.
- try-with-resources automatically closes the PreparedStatement even with a raised exception or break/return.
- When doing both database operations, it seems better to use two (prepared) statements, as the first returns a ResultSet.

So:

```
String sql = SELECT * FROM "+databaseName+"."+tableName + "\n" +
        "WHERE account_tags = ?";
try (PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sq)) {
    statement.setString(1, AccountTag);
    try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to separate statements with an If condition  :

```
String sql1="SELECT * FROM "+databaseName+"."+tableName;

String sql2="DELETE FROM "+databaseName+"."+tableName+" "+
            "WHERE account_tags = '"+AccountTag+"';

    statement.executeQuery(sql1);
    statement.executeUpdate(sql2);
```